# How to upload images to repl.it

Tags: image, replit

I am working on a school video game project in which I am coding a game with friends. Because I am working on a school laptop, I can not download python, so I use repl.it. My friends made graphics to use in the game, but I don't know how to use them on repl.it. Is there any way to uplaod images to repl.it for use in programs? Thanks!Edit: I know there is a way to do this for web languages, but I am using python. Is there any way to do the same in python?

Answer (score 0):

you can upload images in Python in the same way - by clicking on the little cloud icon with the up-arrow above your editor.

See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fO32x.png